# Malt barley powder: pancake killer?

Tags: baking, pancakes, baking-soda, malt

I got some barley malt powder at H Mart

https://hmart.co.uk/shop/en/pan-frying-powder/4496-tureban-dry-malt-barley-powder-400g-8804129001021.html

and tried using it in pancakes.  The pancakes stay gooey and do not rise at all, not one bit, even with extra baking soda and a tiny bit of malt powder.  I realized that the malt powder in the pancake recipes is malted milk so I have the wrong stuff.  But I am curious why malt powder kills the leavening action of baking soda.

---

My pancakes:

```
2 cups flour
2 - 3 Tbsp sunflower oil
1/2 - 1 Tbsp baking powder
1 egg
1 Tbsp sugar
~2/3 cup plain yogurt
add milk until right consistency to pour
```

Comment: Someone else will have to confirm and provide details (unless I get time later) but there are probably active enzymes in there digesting the starch in your flour. The same thing will happen if you add rice syrup to bread dough.

Comment: If you want an answer to this, it would be helpful to include your pancake recipe.